# Prettier indentation is conflicting... with itself?

Tags: eslint, prettier

So I have the infamous VS Code + Prettier + ESLint setup and it mostly works as expected. There are no conflicting rules when prettier formats on save. Running `eslint --fix` also works fine, without conflicting with the formatting that prettier applied **on save**.

The problem is that when I run prettier **from the CLI**, it replaces the indentation from 4 spaces to 2 tabs. The indentation visually remains the same, but it changes the characters used for it (space -> tab). This messes up the git diff.

Here are config files:

**../.vscode/settings.json** <- note that .vscode is the parent directory, so the path to .prettierrc is `client/.prettierrc`

```json
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        "typescript"
    ],
    "prettier.configPath": "client/.prettierrc",
    "prettier.useEditorConfig": false
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "react-hooks",
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": [
                "**/*.test.js",
                "**/*.test.jsx",
                "**/*.test.ts",
                "**/*.test.tsx"
            ],
            "env": {
                "jest": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "react/function-component-definition": "off",
        "import/extensions": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "react/require-default-props": "off",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
        "indent": "off",
        "prettier/prettier": "error"
    },
    "globals": {
        "React": true,
        "expect": true,
        "JSX": true
    }
}
```

**.prettierrc**

```json
{
    "printWidth": 120,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false
}
```

And these are the npm scripts / CLI commands:

```json
        "pretty": "prettier --config .prettierrc --write --use-tabs \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}\"",
        "lint": "eslint ./src --ext .ts,.tsx,.js,.jsx --fix"
```

Regarding VSCode extensions, I have ESLint and Prettier installed.

Answer (score 0):

I got fed up with it and did this instead:

1. Copied the rules from .prettierrc and pasted them into .eslintrc:

```json
       "rules": "prettier/prettier": ["error", {PASTED_RULES_HERE}]"
```

2. Deleted the .prettierrc file
3. Put this in .vscode/settings.json (in my case it literally just has these lines):

```json
{
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        "typescript"
    ],
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true
    },
}
```

That did the trick for me, but I'd still like to know what was wrong with the initial setup...